# chef-run windows unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: java, windows, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to install java jdk 8 onto an ubuntu 16.04 instance using chef-run. Although when it attempts to install I get `Failed to converge target`, when I open the logs I have the following:

```
[2018-06-21T20:24:34+01:00] ERROR: Remote chef-client error follows:
[2018-06-21T20:24:34+01:00] ERROR: SyntaxError: /var/chef-workstation/cache/cookbooks/windows/resources/share.rb:275: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

I have the following structure in my chef-repo:

```
cookbooks
 -- jdk
  -- attributes
   -- default.rb
  -- recipes
   -- default.rb
  metadata.rb
```

Within `attributes/default.rb`:

```
default['java']['install_flavor'] = 'openjdk'
default['java']['jdk'] = '8'
```

Within `recipes/default.rb`:

```
include_recipe 'java'
```

Within `metadata.rb`:

```
name 'name'
maintainer 'maintainer'
maintainer_email 'maintainer_email@email.com'
license 'MIT'
description 'Installs/Configures java'
long_description 'Installs/Configures java'
version '0.1.0'
chef_version '>= 12.14' if respond_to?(:chef_version)

depends 'java', '~> 2.1.0'
```

I can't see what the error is being caused by. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Edit:

If it helps the command i'm using with arguments is the following:
`chef-run -i ~/.ssh/key jack@host jdk`

Comment: Are you using `windows_share` somewhere in this cookbook? The error isn't for Java.

Comment: @brandonmiller No that’s the weird thing. The java cookbook has windows as a dependency but that’s the only reason it’s installed, other than that I do nothing with it.

Comment: Maybe redownload the windows cookbook and upload again?

Comment: @BrandonMiller well I don't download it myself, when i run `chef-run` it downloads it on the instance for me. I've cleared `/var/chef-workstation` on the instance and cleared it on my local machine `~/.chef-workstation` but nothing changes. Weirdly when I run `kitchen test` it passes.

Comment: If you are using a chef server it downloads it from your server. At the beginning of your test kitchen run check which version of the `windows` cookbook is used, then do the same on your instance and check. Test kitchen gets the cookbooks with Berks not from your server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue should be resolved in the latest stable version 0.1.139.

Comment: 0.1.139 deployed this fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in ChefDK 3.0 when using policy tarball exports. It will be fixed in ChefDK 3.1 next week. In the mean time, add this to your `knife.rb` config file:

```
require "mixlib/archive/lib_archive"
Mixlib::Archive::LibArchive.define_singleton_method(:new) { raise LoadError }
```

Just make sure you remove it when you upgrade to 3.1.

Comment: I created `knife.rb` in `~/.chef` and within `~/.chefdk` with no luck. I also created it on the server itself `/var/chef-workstation/.chef` and ran `chef-run` afterwards and none of them work. I still get exactly the same error, is there something I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Ahh sorry, I don't think `chef-run` uses the same config files. You'll just have to wait for a fixed version I think.

Comment: Will the prior version have the same bug?

Comment: Chef run is a new beta project so I’m not sure they have any releases from before the bug was introduced that are still up. I’ll ping that team in the morning though.